# linq-xml Query not returning expected results

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, linqpad

I have the following xml file which consists of html tags, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html>
<head>
<title>
title1
</title>
</head>

<body>
<fragment id="heading1">
<h1>
Heading 1
</h1>
</fragment>
<fragment id="heading2">
<h2>
Heading 2
</h2>
</fragment>
<fragment id="paragraph1">
<p>
Paragraph 1
</p>
</fragment>
</body>                  
</html>
```

I am trying to extract all the fragment ids and display them using linq-xml. The query is shown below:

```
XDocument xelement = XDocument.Load("Path\\To\\XMLFile"); 
var name = from nm in xelement.Descendants("body")
select nm.Element("fragment").Attribute("id").Value;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

The output this query returns is:

> heading1

But what I want is:

> heading1
>   heading2
>   paragraph1

What am I doing wrong? 
Kindly advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested and its working fine!!

```
XDocument po = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
      IEnumerable<string> names = from id in po.Descendants("fragment").Attributes("id") select id.Value;
            string str = string.Empty;
            foreach (var el in names)
            {
                str += el;               
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you Neel. But could u explain wy it did not work with XDocument?

Comment: it works with XDocument see my updated answer @Anvith

Answer (score 2):

You can select the values using

```
IEnumerable<string> names = from id in xelement.Descendants("fragment").Attributes("id") select id.Value;
```

or

```
IEnumerable<string> names = from frag in xelement.Descendants("fragment") select frag.Attribute("id").Value;
```